# Comparison between date codes

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I have an array of values as such:

```
var array_1 = ["1W", "2W", "3W","1M", "2M", "3M", "6M","9M","1Y"]
```

W stands for weeks, M for months, Y for years. How do I do a string comparison such that a comparison between

`"1Y" > "9M"`

will return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the same base, like days for every information and take the letter for an equivalent of days and return the product.

```js
function getDays(string) {
    return string.slice(0, -1) * { W: 7, M: 30, Y: 365 }[string.slice(-1)];
}

var array = ["1W", "2W", "3W","1M", "2M", "3M", "6M","9M","1Y"]

console.log(array.map(getDays));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple decoder that is easy to expand upon.

In essence it filters the numeric value and then returns it multiplied by some constant based upon the what time symbol it finds in the string (W, M, ...).

```js
function decodeDateCode(dateCode) {
  var numeric = parseInt(dateCode.replace(/\D/igm, ''), 10);
  if (dateCode.indexOf("D") >= 0) {
    return numeric;
  }
  if (dateCode.indexOf("W") >= 0) {
    return numeric * 7;
  }
  if (dateCode.indexOf("M") >= 0) {
    return numeric * (365 / 12);
  }
  if (dateCode.indexOf("Y") >= 0) {
    return numeric * 365;
  }
}
//test
var dateCodes = ["1W", "2W", "3W", "1M", "2M", "3M", "6M", "9M", "1Y", "50W"];
//Decode entire list
console.log("Decoded list:", dateCodes.map(decodeDateCode));
//Sort entire list in descending order
console.log("Sorted descending list:", dateCodes.sort(function(a, b) {
  return decodeDateCode(b) - decodeDateCode(a);
}));
//Make simple comparison
console.log("Simple comparison:", decodeDateCode("1Y") > decodeDateCode("9M"));
```